# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Model.User' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Connections'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, signalr

Estou seguindo nesse **[exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)** para manter informações de conexão e usuário em um banco de dados.

Então criei 2 tabelas:

**dbo.User:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**dbo.Connection:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas 2 tabelas acima, são bem simples. Só criei apenas como chave primária.

Então eu criei novo item "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" na pasta "Models".

**Model.Context.cs: (DbContext)**

```
public virtual DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

**Connection.cs:**

```
public partial class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public bool Connected { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs:**

```
public partial class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    //Adicionei esse novo código abaixo:
    public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}
```

Eu recebo o seguinte de erro:

```
Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Model.User' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Connections'.
```

Segue o código:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        var user = db.Users.Include(u => u.Connections).SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new User
            {
                UserName = name,
                Connections = new List<Connection>()
            };
            db.Users.Add(user);
        }

        user.Connections.Add(new Connection
        {
            ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
            UserAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"],
            Connected = true
        });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

O problema está ocorrendo na linha: `var user = db.Users.Include(u => u.Connections).SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name);`.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Tem uma resposta [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637776/a-specified-include-path-is-not-valid-the-entitytype-does-not-declare-a-navigat) que pode te ajudar a entender o porque do problema.

Answer (score 1):

A *navigation property* "Connections" deve ser declarada como virtual:

```
public partial class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    //Adicionei esse novo código abaixo:
    public virtual ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Marcell Alves, não funcionou, continua mesmo problema.

Comment: Marcell Alves, consegui resolver problema, esqueci de colocar relacionamentos entre 2 tabelas. Agora o problema está ocorrendo na linha : `db.SaveChanges();` Error: Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: E qual está sendo a mensagem retornada pela propriedade 'Entity ValidationErrors'?

Comment: Aqui está `{System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}`

Comment: Na verdade, precisamos do conteúdo dessa mensagem, que vai indicar com precisão o erro que está ocorrendo. Utilize a opção "ViewDetail" do Visual Studio quando o erro ocorrer e navegue dentro das propriedades da exceção levantada para encontrar o texto do conteúdo dessa propriedade.

Comment: https://s8.postimg.org/q4t2h94x1/52_Mar_14_15_04.jpg

Comment: Para conseguir visualizar o real valor dessa propriedade, você vai precisar utilizar o "QuickWatch" do Visual Studio, segue um link descrevendo como: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33264768/3090945

Comment: Agora sim, mostra o porque esse problema: `ErrorMessage "O campo UserAgent deve ser uma cadeia de caracteres ou tipo de matriz com comprimento máximo de '50'."`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55375/discussion-between-matheus-miranda-and-marcell-alves).